# jQuery trigger hover on a different element

Tags: jquery

When the user is hovering on a element i want a hover event be triggered on a different div.

**Html**

```
<div id="SubmitTabs">Hover here</div>

<div id="UploadedFile">Hover event will trigger here</div>
```

**Css**

```
#UploadedFile {
    background-color:blue;
}

    #UploadedFile:hover {
        background-color: black;
    }
```

**Ive tried both of these:**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#SubmitTabs").hover(function () {
                $("UploadedFile").mouseover();
            });

            $('#SubmitTabs').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
                $('UploadedFile').trigger(e.type);
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Why in the world is this not working..?

Thank you..!!!

Edit 1: Alert is working when i hover

http://jsfiddle.net/nRYra/16/

Alerts not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do something like this in your css instead?

```
#SubmitTabs:hover + #UploadedFile {
  background-color: black;
}
```

**Edit:** Fixed your fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nRYra/17/

```
#UploadedFile {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 80px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    border-color: #f9f9f9;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#SubmitTabs:hover + #UploadedFile {
            background-color: #e5f3fb;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #70c0e7;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as i said before every suggestion works great in fiddle, but nothing works in my project. So frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

you were close:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#SubmitTabs").hover(function () {
            $("#UploadedFile").trigger('mouseover');
        });

        $('#UploadedFile').on('mouseover', function (e) {
            alert('alerted from hovering over Submit Tab');
            $(this).css({ 'color' : '#000' });
            // do anything you want
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        })
    });
```

Comment: I tried .hover aswell but it didnt work for me either.. Your code isnt working for me im afraid...

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#SubmitTabs").on('mouseenter mouseleave',function () {
            $("#UploadedFile").toggleClass('hover');
        });
    });
```

And do your stuff on css

Comment: This and every other script that is posted should work but it doesnt. Something else must be causing this

Comment: can you put on the jsfiddle so we can help you betteR?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nRYra/16/
Is alerts disabled in fiddle? It works in my project